# What are the differences between these CSS lines

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```css
#cssmenu ul li.hover,
#cssmenu ul li:hover {position: relative; z-index: 599; cursor: default;}
#cssmenu ul ul {visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; z-index: 598; width: 100%;}
#cssmenu ul ul li {float: none;}
```

1) what is the difference between "li.hover" and "li:hover"?

2) what does "ul ul li" even mean? why are there 2 "ul" elements?

Answer (score 5):

`li.hover` is targeting an `li` element that also has a class of `hover`, for example:

```
<li class="hover"></li>
```

`li:hover` is targeting the hovered state of any `li` element.

`ul ul li` is targeting any `li` elements that reside in a `ul` element that resides inside *another* `ul` element, like so:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>This is the element that would be targeted</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. Where can I see the list of these states (like :hover) ?

Comment: @DarkNight see it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes).

Comment: Both Pangloss's and Oriol's resource recommendations are excellent. I'd recommend _not_ relying on any information from w3schools.org, if anybody suggests that as a resource.

Comment: Sidenote: Chrome has an awesome extension called "W3Schools Hider" that'll keep any w3schools.com stuff out of your Google search results. :-)

Comment: why is w3schools.org bad?

Comment: Many of their examples are *very* poorly coded and in some cases, just plain wrong. This link probably details why not to use it the best - [http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com)

Comment: Essentially, even if an answer you get from w3schools.com actually works for you, chances are it'll teach you very bad coding practices that'll cause you a lot of headaches down the road. You'll be much better served by learning from official documentation, as recommended by Pangloss and Oriol.

Answer (score 1):

`.hover` is a class identifier

`:hover` denotes the action of `mouseOver`

Comment: Cold you also tell me what this is: ul li:hover > ul

Comment: Stile of `ul` on hover of `li` inside another `ul`

Comment: Also, where can i see a list of these symbols, like ">" ?

Comment: I would _strongly_ recommend against relying on w3schools.com for any information. Instead, I would checkout MDN - `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors`

Comment: Important note about `ul li:hover > ul` - it's not *just* for a `ul` inside of a hovered `ul li`. The `>` means that only a `ul` that's the *direct descendant* of the `ul li` is targeted - i.e. if the last `ul` element in that selector was actually inside of an `a` element, then the `ul li:hover > ul` selector will not target it.

Answer (score 1):

1) 
`li.hover` is a defined class. You can use it like `<li class="hover">`.
`li:hover` defines the hover state. It will appear if you hover an element with your cursor.

2)
`ul ul li` : The second `ul` styles a `ul` in an available `ul`. It can be used for sublists.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. Where can I see the list of these states (like :hover) ?

Comment: Again, I would recommend *not* relying on w3schools.com.

Answer (score -1):

1) 
li.hover li element which have class hover exp ..
li:hover li element which are being hovered.

2) 
ul ul li only li element which have at least ul as ancestors exp:

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <ul>
   <li>
      ME
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```